# About the proof of Nullstellensatz

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Let $\mathfrak{m}$ be a maximal ideal in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. Then $K:=k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/\mathfrak{m}$ is a field. Moreover $K$ is also a finitely generated $k$-algebra, so by Zariski's Lemma $K$ is algebraic over $k$.

I can't prove what follows: since $k$ is algebraically closed, the natural map
$$\phi:k\hookrightarrow k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\twoheadrightarrow k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/\mathfrak{m}=K$$
is an isomorphism between $k$ and $K$. I know that since $k$ is algebraically closed, every algebraic extension of $k$ equals $k$, but how can be proven that $\phi$ is a particular isomorphism?

Comment: Note that $\phi$ is one-to-one. As $K$ is algebraic over $k$ and $k$ is closed, it cannot be a proper injection. Hence its onto and therefore an isomorphism.

Comment: @martini thanks for your comment. Honestly I can't see the injectivity.

Comment: @martini Well, I think one hsould simply note that $\phi$ is the identity on $k$. (A priori, it might be that $k$ is isomorphic to a subfield of itself)

Comment: @bateman Injectivity is trivial as fields lack ideals.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Oh yes I know that, but now I can't understand your further remark: $\phi$ is the identity on $k$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A homomorphism from a field to a nontrivial ring is injective (since the kernel is a proper ideal, hence zero). In particular, every homomorphism between fields is actually a field extension. Now use that an algebraically closed field has only one algebraic field extension, namely itsself.

Comment: Brandeburg Ok, but HagenvonEitzen pointed out that k might be isomorphic to a proper subfield of itself, how can I exclude this case?

Comment: This doesn't matter here.